A question on electromagnetic induction in inductors
If a voltage is applied across an inductor then the induced voltage created by it is often assumed to be the same as the applied voltage. Why?

As long as they are not the same I is changing till I=0

"Induced voltage" on inductor is a somewhat confusing/ambiguous term. It can mean either induced EMF (this seems to be the use in some EM theory/electric engineering textbooks), which is a line integral of induced electric field $\mathbf E_i$ over the path that starts at terminal 1, goes inside the inductor coils, and ends up at terminal 2:
$$
\mathscr{E} = \int_{1\to2~through~coils}\mathbf E_i\cdot d\mathbf s.
$$
In simplified language, induced EMF is work of induced electric field acting on unit charge, when the charge goes from one terminal to another, via the prescribed path.
It is customary to express value of this integral in terms of current rate of change:
$$
\mathscr{E} = - L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
Induced electric field $\mathbf E_i$ is a component of net electric field $\mathbf E$ that is not conservative.
As you can see, this, by definition, has nothing to do directly with electric potential difference.
There is also another component of net electric field, the conservative component $\mathbf E_c$. Net field  is the sum $\mathbf E = \mathbf E_i + \mathbf E_c$.
Less often (and it's really a misleading use of the term), "induced voltage" can also mean "voltage" in the sense as it is used in circuit theory, that is, difference of electric potential between the inductor terminals. This potential difference is defined as integral of the conservative component of electric field:
$$
V = \int_1^2\mathbf E_c\cdot d\mathbf s.
$$
Here, the path does not matter.
Thus we can see these two quantities - induced EMF $\mathscr{E}$ and potential difference $V$ - are different concepts, and in general, they also have different values.
However, in the special idealized case where the inductor is made of perfect conductor, net electric field inside the coils $\mathbf E =0$ even while current flows, and we have $\mathbf E_c = -\mathbf E_i$ there. We can use this to express potential difference integral in terms of induced EMF:
$$
V = \int_{1\to2~through~coils}- \mathbf E_i\cdot d\mathbf s = -\mathscr{E}
$$
and thus we can also express it in terms of current:
$$
V = L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
However, if the inductor is a real device, it has some resistance and also capacitance and if it has a core, also hysteresis. Then net electric field in the coils isn't zero, and changes with current. Then, such simple relation between induced EMF and potential difference $V$ (equality of magnitudes) does not hold.
In the simple case where the real inductor behaves as perfect inductor with resistance $R$ in series, we can still find the new relation. From Kirchhoff's second circuital law and assuming the potential difference is fixed by an ideal voltage source, we can derive the relation between EMF and potential difference on such inductor:
$$
\mathscr{E} + V = RI.
$$
From this, we can again express potential difference in terms of current:
$$
V = RI + L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
In case $R=0$, we get the usual relation valid for perfect inductor, but if resistance is not zero, we can see induced EMF and potential difference have different magnitudes.

I knew my answer was a slight lie but I thought a simpler explanation could be more suited to the style of the question. Your answer is simply better so I deleted mine.
